# Yii2 Home Breadcrumbs incorrect

Tags: yii2, breadcrumbs

For some reason the home url for the breadcrumbs in my website is incorrect :
e.g. 
 the breadcrumbs are Home / Biometries
when I click on Home - i get (with 404 error)
basic/web/index.phpindex.php

How can I correct the home url to leave off the extra index.php?
I've searched the app and the Yii2 Site with no help
Thanks

Comment: Seems a URL formatting problem, please show your code

Comment: I found the error, on my main layout page -    <?= Breadcrumbs::widget([
                'homeLink' => ['label' => 'Home', 'url'=>Yii::$app->getHomeUrl().'index.php?r=dashboard/index'],
                'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
            ]) ?>  ------ Just dropped the index.php there and it works fine - This always happens when I spend hours looking for this bit of code Thanks for making me get more precise...

Answer (score 5):

I found the error, on my main layout page

```
<?=
    Breadcrumbs::widget([
        'homeLink' => ['label' => 'Home',
        'url' => Yii::$app->getHomeUrl() . 'index.php?r=dashboard/index'],
        'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [], 
    ]);
?>
```

Just dropped the index.php there and it works fine - This always happens when I spend hours looking for this bit of code Thanks for making me get more precise..